Bound on number of extensions of Q unramified outside a fixed prime
Are there any known asymptotic bounds on the number of degree $d$ extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ unramified outside a fixed prime $p$?

Are you asking for a bound assuming $p$ is fixed and $d \rightarrow \infty$?

Precisely, I hope this was clear from my phrasing.

For each $d$, let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. If $K$ is unramified outside of $\{p\}$, then its discriminant must be a power of $p$, up to sign. Then there exists $k \geq 1$ such that $\Delta(K) = \varepsilon_K p^k$, where $\varepsilon_K = \pm 1$. Let $v$ be a prime above $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Then $K_v$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree at most $d$. By Krasner's Lemma there are only finitely many possibilities for $K_v$. This implies the $p$-adic valuation of $\Delta(K)$ has a bounded number of possibilities. By our assumption, this means that $|\Delta(K)|$ is bounded in terms of $p, d$ alone, say $|\Delta(K)| \leq C(p,d)$. Inserting this into what looks like the best bound for $N_n(X)$, the number of number fields of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and discriminant bounded by $X$ due to Lemke-Oliver and Thorne, we get an upper bound of the shape
$$\displaystyle C(p,d)^{c(\log d)^2}$$
for some universal constant $c$. This is probably the best that can be hoped for.
There is some hope of a better bound if we can phrase the question as one about counting $S$-integral solutions to some diophantine equation, but it is not clear to me how this would work.

Is there any known bound on $C(p,d)$?

@YCor yes, a bound can be extracted from Krasner's lemma. I will write down the details when I have time.

I guess the Lemke-Oliver Thorne bound allows $\Delta(K)$ to have unrestricted ramification, so it doesn't strike me as quite optimal. In fact, I was mostly curious at the dependence in $d$. Is there any chance the precise dependence in $d$ is exponential rather than super-exponential? Is there any data/conjectures on this?
